# What does immutability mean in the definition of the nCopies API in JAVA ?What is an use case for this API?

Tags: arraylist, collections, java

I came across a `nCopies` code somewhere and not being familiar with this funciton, I looked up the [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies(int,%20T)) and noticed that the definition says :

*Returns an immutable list consisting of n copies of the specified object.*

What does immutable to mean here ?I thought immutable meant that it cannot be modified. However, I notice that I am able to modify it . Also, I am able to reassign some other list to it.

This is the sample code I wrote to check the behavior .

```
   public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(5,0));
        List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        list2.add(2);list2.add(3); 
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            int prod = i*2;
            list.set(i, prod); // list is modifiable
        }
        print(list);
        list = list2; // list is assignable
        print(list);
    }
```

What is an use case of this API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `List<Integer> list = Collections.nCopies(5,0);` - your version passes the immutable collection to the [`ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) constructor, which copies it. The copy **is** mutable.